# How can i play animated gif inside a custom page in nsis?

Tags: gif, nsis, animated-gif

I'm building an NSIS/MUI2 installer and i want to add a custom page that plays a gif for a few seconds and with bitmap on that page as well and then move to the next page automatically. I can't seem to do it correctly. Can you guide me how can i do it?

Here is my code:

```
OutFile "Example.exe"


XPStyle on
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh ; MAKELONG

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom nsDialogsPageEnter nsDialogsPageExit
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH





Function nsDialogsPageEnter
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0


    ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 30% 30% 80% 80% ""
    Pop $0
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\img.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\arrow.bmp"
    ${NSD_SetImage} $0 "$pluginsdir\img.bmp" $1

    newadvsplash::show /NOUNLOAD 1200 250 0 -1 /BANNER /NOCANCEL "$PLUGINSDIR\test.gif"
    newadvsplash::hwnd /NOUNLOAD
    Pop $0
    AnimGif::play /NOUNLOAD /hwnd=$0 "$PLUGINSDIR\test.gif"

    ;slow functions

    Sleep 3000

    newadvsplash::stop
    AnimGif::stop



    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageExit
FunctionEnd

Section "-Main"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted fails to extract test.gif!

Beyond that, using `Sleep` on a page is usually not a good idea because it locks up the UI.

Play GIF on top of bitmap control:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom nsDialogsPageEnter
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function beginanimfunc
${NSD_KillTimer} ${__FUNCTION__}
${NSD_SetImage} $0 "$pluginsdir\img.bmp" $1
AnimGif::play /NOUNLOAD /HALIGN=0 /VALIGN=0 /HWND=$0 /BGCOL=0x0000ff "$PLUGINSDIR\anim.gif"
${NSD_CreateTimer} stopanimfunc 2000
FunctionEnd

!include WinMessages.nsh
Function stopanimfunc
${NSD_KillTimer} ${__FUNCTION__}
AnimGif::stop
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_COMMAND} 1 "" ; Click next button
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageEnter
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    StrCpy $1 ""
    ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 30% 30% 80% 80% ""
    Pop $0
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\img.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\arrow.bmp"
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\anim.gif" "C:\myfiles\myanim.gif"
    ${NSD_CreateTimer} beginanimfunc 1

    nsDialogs::Show
    ${NSD_FreeImage} $1
FunctionEnd
```

Play GIF in splash popup:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom nsDialogsPageEnter
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include WinMessages.nsh
Function stopanimfunc
${NSD_KillTimer} ${__FUNCTION__}
newadvsplash::stop /FADEOUT
AnimGif::stop
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_COMMAND} 1 "" ; Click next button
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageEnter
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    StrCpy $1 ""
    ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 30% 30% 80% 80% ""
    Pop $0
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\img.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\arrow.bmp"
    ${NSD_SetImage} $0 "$pluginsdir\img.bmp" $1
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\anim.gif" "C:\myfiles\myanim.gif"

    newadvsplash::show /NOUNLOAD 1200 250 0 -1 /BANNER /NOCANCEL /PASSIVE "" ; <- you can put a bitmap here also
    newadvsplash::hwnd /NOUNLOAD
    Pop $0
    AnimGif::play /NOUNLOAD /HALIGN=0 /VALIGN=0 /HWND=$0 /BGCOL=0x0000ff "$PLUGINSDIR\anim.gif"
    ${NSD_CreateTimer} stopanimfunc 2000
    nsDialogs::Show
    ${NSD_FreeImage} $1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: this example works perfectly. But i need to do some heavy job while this gif is playing. and when i try to add it something goes wrong with the gif.

Comment: You are not supposed to do heavy work outside Sections. Use the BgWorker plug-in if you need to do background work on a page.